# How do I get the keys of the sorted values in an array

Tags: javascript, sorting

If I have the following array: [5, 1, -7, 3, 6, 8, 0, -1, -3]

By sorting it I get [-7, -3, -1, 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8]

That's fine, but what I want is the keys for the array when sorted.
This: [2, 8, 7, 6, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5]

I tried the following using insertion sort, but of course this is wrong.

```
var arr = [5, 1, -7, 3, 6, 8, 0, -1, -3];
keys = new Array(arr.length);
for(var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    key = arr[j];
    var i = j - 1;
    while(i >= 0 && arr[i] > key) {
        keys[i+1] = i;
        i--;
    }
    arr[i+1] = key;
    keys[i+1] = j;
}
```

Am I on the right track? Can you help me out here :)

Comment: This is an excellently put-forward question. You provided sample input, sample output, and also what you've tried so far. Well done.

Comment: Thank you :)  I'm amazed by the quick answers.

Comment: Whichever you feel helped you the most, or would help others the most, or is the clearest. It's up to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the kind of thing described on this page

http://www.webdotdev.com/nvd/content/view/878/.

Basically, make each item in the array an object with two properties (the sort-key and its index in the array), then sort them by the key.

Comment: I can't see why either. This was the answer fitting best for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may not want to sort the array, just return an array of the sorted indexes-

```
var A= [5, 1, -7, 3, 6, 8, 0, -1, -3], i, L=A.length, B=[];

for(i=0;i<L;i++) B[i]=[A[i],i];

B.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]});

for(var i=0;i<L;i++)B[i]=B[i].pop();

A+'\n'+ B
```

returned value:

5,1,-7,3,6,8,0,-1,-3

2,8,7,6,1,3,0,4,5 // sort order indexes

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [5, 1, -7, 3, 6, 8, 0, -1, -3];

// Create an array that pairs the values with the indices
for (var paired=[],i=0,len=els.length;i<len;++i) paired[i] = [arr[i],i];
// result: [[5,0],[1,1],[-7,2],[3,3],[6,4],[8,5],[0,6],[-1,7],[-3,8]]

// Sort that array by the values (first element)
paired.sort(function(a,b){ a=a[0]; b=b[0]; return a<b?-1:a>b?1:0; });
// result: [[-7,2],[-3,8],[-1,7],[0,6],[1,1],[3,3],[5,0],[6,4],[8,5]]

// Create another array that has just the (now-sorted) indices (second element)
for (var indices=[],i=0;i<len;++i) indices[i] = paired[i][1];
// result: [2, 8, 7, 6, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You mean elsWithI.sort(function(a,b){..., and
Not elsWithI(function...  right? :)

Comment: @Dag Oops, thanks. The method call was a victim of a double-click-select-and-paste when shortening lines.